# Min and max value with ROS2 Parameter

Tags: ros, ros2, parameter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everyone,

The dynamic reconfigure is not available in ROS2, and its replacement Parameter feature is used.
With ROS, .cfg files are used, where parameter's value, min , max and other details can be given.
With ROS2, I tried to set parameter with value and its working fine, but is there a way to set min and max value for that parameter?
e.g. of .cfg

```
gen.add ("min_x", double_t, 0, "X coordinate of the minimum point of the box.", -1, -1000, 1000)
```

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/311922/min-and-max-value-with-ros2-parameter/) by [poonam1120](https://answers.ros.org/users/38719/poonam1120/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2019-01-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is currently (as of Crystal) no comparable feature to declare parameter boundaries.

Once the change to IDL has landed I imagine that it will be possible to create an `.idl` which declares the parameters of a node including their valid range (like `.cfg` files in ROS 1 but language agnostic).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2019-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-04**:\

> Once the change to IDL has landed [..]

*the* change?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-01-04**:
https://github.com/ros2/rosidl/pull/298

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2019-01-04**:
@gvdhoorn This is a change to add support for IDL messages in addition to msg format.

**Comment by [poonam1120](https://answers.ros.org/users/38719/poonam1120/) on 2019-01-04**:
Thanks all for the response

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-04**:
@tfoote: I was/am aware of the IDL work :) Just thought it would be nice if @Dirk Thomas could link to a PR / issue as that would make his answer better.